# Invalid Cast Exception, Stored Procedure, LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

9 months later, the same problem shows up again. I've tried everything I can think of:

- I cast as varchar(max) on the stored procedure;
- I changed the mapping;
- tried to find the collection linq works with, but couldn't find anywhere;

I have been running this stored procedure for some time Mapping it to my objects using LINQ to SQL, and now, all of the sudden, LINQ is trying to cast the field 'value' as double.

---

**the error:**

```
specified cast is not valid    
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Double()
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDouble(Int32 i)
   Read_Field(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   CmsCsharp.BL.FieldManager.FindContentField(Int32 id_content, Int32 id_fieldType, String fieldName)
```

---

**the methods**

```
public static Field FindContentField(int id_content, int id_fieldType, string fieldName)
            {
                using (DbBase conn = new DbBase())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return conn.ClientDB.sprocFindContentField(id_content, id_fieldType, fieldName).Single();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }



[Function(Name = "dbo.sprocFindContentField")]
        public ISingleResult<Field> sprocFindContentField([Parameter(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> id_content, [Parameter(DbType="Int")]System.Nullable<int> id_fieldType, [Parameter(DbType="Varchar(255)")]string fieldName)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), id_content, id_fieldType, fieldName);
            return ((ISingleResult<Field>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

---

**the field:**

```
public class TextField : Field
{
   private string _Value;

    [Column(Storage="_Value", DbType="VarChar(MAX) NOT NULL", Name="value", CanBeNull=true)]
    public string Value
    { //get and set }
}
```

---

**the procedure:**

```
  SELECT 
         type = 'textField',
         fieldLabel.id_fieldEditor,
         fieldLabel.id_fieldType ,
         fieldLabel.description,
         fieldLabel.id ,         
         sessionField.id  AS relationId,
         fieldLabel.name ,
         fieldText.content AS value,
         fieldText.id  AS valueId,
         cf.id as contentRelationId
  FROM
         fieldLabel
  INNER JOIN
         sessionField
  ON
         sessionField.id_fieldLabel = fieldLabel.id
  INNER JOIN
        cms_contentField AS cf
  ON
        cf.id_sessionField = sessionField.id
  INNER JOIN
         fieldText
  ON
         fieldText.id = cf.id_fieldValue
  INNER JOIN
        fieldType
  ON
        fieldLabel.id_fieldType = fieldType.id
  INNER JOIN
        fieldTable
  ON
        fieldTable.id = fieldType.id_fieldTable
  WHERE
         cf.id_content = @id_content
  AND
        fieldTable.id = 1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... what from that error message pointed you to that particular field?

Comment: Could you post your database table's schema?

Comment: Marcg Gravell: Because if i remove the Mapping to the field, the exception is not raised.

Comment: id_fieldEditor int,
id_fieldType int,
description varchar(1500),
id int,
relationId int,
name varchar(255),
value varchar(max),
valueId int,
contentRelationId int

Comment: I just wanna know why he tries a get_double, when there's no field that is double...

Comment: Can you show some context regarding the code? Maybe part of the FindContentField method would be helpful.

Comment: I've edited and put the code of the methods related to the error. But it happens when i call it from other methods (Like when i call a list of TextFields), so I guess it's on that specific mapping.

Comment: Okay, i've got some old files, from a old version, and is working now. Still, I can't identify the problem.

Comment: Okay, 9 months later, same problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the 9th line in the stored procedure to *fieldText.content,*

```
SELECT 
     type = 'textField',
     fieldLabel.id_fieldEditor,
     fieldLabel.id_fieldType ,
     fieldLabel.description,
     fieldLabel.id ,         
     sessionField.id  AS relationId,
     fieldLabel.name ,
     fieldText.content AS value, //this line
     fieldText.id  AS valueId,
     cf.id as contentRelationId
```

then I changed the mapping accordingly:

```
[Column(Storage="_Value", DbType="VarChar(MAX) NOT NULL", Name="content", CanBeNull=true)]
public string Value
{ //get and set }
```

and it worked!

Have no idea why it worked. Does the labeling (as value) could be the cause?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a value in your table that is triggering SQL Server's conversion through the "numeric" data type. i.e. your value is being converted into an imprecise data type (float or real) and causing LINQ to SQL to attempt a double. See the caution in [SQL Server's help file for int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

Comment: i don't gave any field as numeric. I've put a comment on the OP with the types of each field. thank you

Comment: I saw that. But if you read that link, you'll see that certain transactions in a parameterized query will convert an int to a numeric and thus return a numeric value which, since it is an imprecise data type, will be handled as a double by .Net.

Comment: interesting. But i'm pretty sure that the problem is in the 'value' field, since the exception is not raised if i comment the line that maps the field to the property. And that field is a varchar(max), so, i don't see how the int problem would apply in this case. Do you know any good way of finding out exactly which field is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm arriving late with the same error message in the same context.

The problem was an unamed column in my Proc Stock result. No problem to excute it in management studio. No problem to register it in my dbml, but invalid cast at runtime.

Hope that helps